# how to fadeIn an image using <img> tag instead of a <div> using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-effects

I'm trying out some jQuery for the first time.  My first goal is for one image on the page to fade into a different image.  I've figured out how to do this with a couple of divs that have background-image set to the different image files (see code below).  However, this would work better for my situation if I was somehow doing this to an existing img tag instead of using some divs.  Is there any way to do what this code does, but with the img tag?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function() {
          $("#imgblock2").delay(3000).fadeIn(3000);
      });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
      #imgblock {
        background-image:url("frame.jpg");
        width:240;
        height:320;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
      }
      #imgblock2 {
        background-image:url("average.jpg");
        width:240;
        height:320;
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        display:none;
      }
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="imgblock"></div>
    <div id="imgblock2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Use actual images instead of divs. you an give the images id's as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have a container div that includes both images and set its `position` to relative. After that you can put both images inside that div and give them id's, be sure to set their `position` to absolute so that they are layered on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

[This is not that hard ;)](http://jsfiddle.net/A6bHX/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var relatedImg =  $("#imgblock");

   relatedImg.css("display", "none");
   relatedImg.fadeIn("slow", function(){
       relatedImg.fadeOut("slow", function(){
           relatedImg.attr("src", "http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5221/5592275221_8190eb9b9c.jpg");
           relatedImg.fadeIn("slow");
       }); 

    });
});
```

**Explanation**

At first, we set the display property to "none" via javascript (so customers without would just see the image) after the `fadeIn` we `fadeOut` our image and change the image src with the `attr` function.

Comment: Why so many jquery objects created for the same element? Cache the item - var imgBlock = $("#imgblock")

Comment: I'll avoid any retort to the abuse and keep it technical. The point of answering questions here is to show best practice, not sloppy code to get by.